# Custom capture layout zxing barcode scanner

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a custom layout to take not the fullscreen of the app but when i modify someting to the layout it crashes

I use this library :
https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#adding-aar-dependency-with-gradle

the custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (C) 2008 ZXing authors
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
 -->
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/zxing_preview_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView
        android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zxing_result_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/zxing_result_view"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/zxing_standard_padding">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxWidth="160dip"
                    android:maxHeight="160dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_format"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_format_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_type"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_type_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_time"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_time_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_meta_text_view_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_meta"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_meta_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_contents_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textColorLink="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_contents_supplement_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textColorLink="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zxing_result_button_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_status_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
            android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_status"
            android:textColor="@color/zxing_status_text"/>

        <Button android:id="@id/zxing_back_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/zxing_button_cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and what i can say is that the library tries to get all those views with the zxing_ prefix    when it loads the layout, so if the library does not find all those views, it throws exceptions when tries to call methods on them. So to work around this problem, i included  all the zxing_ views in my layout and set the visibility to "gone" on all of them that i wanted to not show.

Comment: Yeah i tried but is it possible to have the capture view with the action bar at the top